# Change email Display name power automate flow

Tags: sharepoint-online, email, flow, power-automate, microsoft-flow

Looking to see if there is a way to modify the display name on an email sent via a flow?

Using the "Send an Email (V2)" function. In the "From (send as)" field I chose the double arrow option for "Advanced Mode" and it allows you to write an email in there without the auto suggest. I tried typing the email in the following format:

```
Custom Name <info@xyzdomain.com>
```

However I get an error that it does not like this format. I want to be able to specify the "Custom Name" so that the recipient sees that instead of the default name that the info@xyzdomain.com has.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [Send an email (V2)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/office365/#send-an-email-(v2)) action documentation,

**From (Send as)** is of type **email** & has description:

> Email address to send mail from (requires "Send as" or "Send on behalf of" permission for that mailbox). For more info on granting permissions please refer https://docs.microsoft.com/office365/admin/manage/send-email-as-distribution-list

[image]

So, you **cannot** pass the custom name format (string) in **From (Send as)** field.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Ganesh Sanap.

According to my research, the **[Send an email (V2) action](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/office365/#send-an-email-(v2))** does not support set custom name format (string) in **From (Send as) field**.